# Increase the call-frequency for the touchesMoved-method

Tags: iphone, drawing, touchesmoved

I am currently working on an app, which includes a paint function. It actually doesn't work that bad, but the problem is, that the refresh-rate or the frequency of the calls for the touchesMoved-method is too bad.

If you move the fingers fast over the screen, the lines get many edges and it doesn't look that good. So i thought about increasing the call-frequency for this method. Would that be a good and even possible solution for my problem?

Maybe you can help me with my problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this approach: Look at Adobe's Ideas App on the AppStore. If touchesEnd, work with `NSBezierPath` to get a smoother look without edges. You basically store the points in touchesMoved in an array? So you got the points to insert in the Bezier Path functions. You have a edgy look **while** drawing but after **releasing** it looks kind of smooth. I did so in one of my projects and result is fairly okay.

(But there are many other approaches to build a drawing application.)

**Demo App from Apple:** [Click here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/BezierPathLab/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008880)